# Electron - develop for Windows on Mac

Tags: virtual-machine, electron, electron-builder, electron-forge

I'm starting a project that is for a Windows desktop app with Electron, however development will be done on a Mac.

Currently, in order to run the app on Windows, I have to package up the project, and then run the `.exe` on the Virtual Machine.

Does anyone have an efficient setup for this situation that enables live updates and hot reloading during development?

Comment: I'm assuming you have some form of version control? Sync the files and run the dev environment on windows. Does the VM have Node/build tools installed?

Comment: Correct. It does have those installed.

Comment: Well assuming you used their scaffolding tool you should just be able to run it with `npm start`

Comment: Thanks! That is a good back up plan, but I'm mainly looking for something that can take advantage of hot module reloading while developing on my Mac.

Comment: Ah.. Got no idea. Perhaps some finagling with this? https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/11/15/live-share

Comment: Just setup up vs on both environments and see what happens?

Comment: Do you package your windows version on mac os?